# How can I modify my code for Array Empty Run without Time error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Leetcode 2659. Make Array Empty

I wrote this code and it works fine but in testcase 469 it fails due to time exceeding.
Can anyone suggest thing to reduce the time complexity with the same logic I approached ?

```
result=0
while len(nums)>0:
    if nums[0]==min(nums):
        result+=1
        nums.remove(nums[0])
    else:
        nums.insert(len(nums),nums.pop(0))
        result+=1`
print(result)
```

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to understand the problem. Post more context. Note: don't expect us to go and look up leetcode problems for clarity - we won't ;) Give information about what you are trying to do, better yet also give some sample input and output. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
result = 0
while len(nums) > 0:
    min_value = min(nums)
    min_index = nums.index(min_value)
    result += min_index + 1  # Increment result by min_index + 1
    nums = nums[min_index + 1:]  # Remove elements before min_index
print(result)
```